# Changing file permissions of auto-mounted hot-plugged FAT32 USB partition

Tags: permissions, usb-drive, fat32

Linux can read from, write to and execute files (vfat driver) formatted as FAT32. Auto-mounting (in my case Ubuntu) leads however to all files owned by root and not executable.

By changing the file /etc/fstab these permissions can be changed. Indeed files can now be owned by any user and can be made executable by everyone. However this is a static solution. The USB disk has to be plugged in on start-up. Re-plugging the same stick restores the old root-owned situation. To get the partition re-owned by a user and executable by everyone a "umount" and a "mount" has to be performed. This is irritating, not in the last place because "mount" requires root privilege.

Is it possible to create a situation than when a USB stick with a FAT32 partition on it is hot-plugged into a running Linux system that FAT32 partition is auto-mounted with such permissions that world can write to it and execute files on it?

Comment: The problem is it's going to depend on what auto mounter is being used.  Is it Gnome?  Then you might be able to do something with dconf-editor.  It could be pmount, or maybe udisks?  It's hard to tell--seems like different desktops and distros use different methods.